# What will happen if there's an if statement in Peterson's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, command, mutual-exclusion

I have read this for Peterson's algorithm for mutual exclusion, and I had a question in what would happen if in the final statement in the enter portion to the critical section has an if statement on it:

```
flag[j] = true;
turn = j
if(turn ==j)
      while(flag[k]);
```

I figured there would be mutual exclusion as if one process goes through the first two statements, the second process could sneak in it's first statement before the first process heads into the important section, and then the second process can get in after wards, thereby ruining the property but I wasn't sure about fairness or liveliness?

Comment: Are you still doing this for only 2 processes?  If not, you've failed to generalize.  If so, why did you switch the notation to parameters `j` and `k`?

Comment: Only two processes, I switched the notation as I was hearing someone said J.K while I was writing it and it just got stuck in my head. Weird I know but shrug.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you separate the checks, then it's no longer Peterson's algorithm, for exactly the reason you've noted: between the two operations, another process can sneak in.

Any effect on fairness and liveness (not "liveliness") would need to hinge on the same separation point.  Since the change makes the algorithm monotonically more permissive, it follows that both of those properties are still intact -- with the caveat that mutual exclusion is now broken.

Comment: Between the two operations you mean between the first two statements and the if statement right? Just wanna be clear of what I consider what I wrote before to be right or not.

Comment: I'm talking about the division between the `if` and `while` that you introduced.

Comment: Ah so the mutual exclusion happens if one process goes all the way to the if statement, and checks that, but then the second process goes all the way through into the CS?